# ZMQ in Python: New socket object for each incoming connection

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq

Sockets in ZMQ are simply bound to an interface and are then able to receive messages right away, like this:

```
socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")
message = socket.recv()
```

Since multiple connections can send data to that socket simultaneously, **how to distinguish the different senders?**

On the other hand, with regular sockets, incoming connections are first accepted, which spawns a new socket, like this:

```
serversocket.bind((socket.gethostname(), 5555))
serversocket.listen()
(clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
```

Here, the different senders can be easily distinguished since each is received through a different socket.

What is the best way to benefit from the convenience message-based and queue-buffered communication of ZMQ but still create an arbitrary number of distinguishable one-on-one connections as soon as they are requested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to distinguish the different clients depends on what socket type your using as your 'server', the explanations below will hopefully answer the 2nd question too.

`REQ` - Will reply to the client that sent the request, a `recv` call on a `REQ` socket must be followed by a `send` so you can't service the next request until you have processed the first. However multiple requests from different clients will be queued.

`ROUTER` - Will append a frame onto the message you `recv` that contains the client id of the sender. When sending a message the first frame will be removed and used to identify which connected client to reply to. You should store all frames up to and including the empty delimiter frame and prepend them to your reply message when you send the reply. Unlike `REQ` there is no need to `send` any messaged before another call to `recv`. The client id will be generated by ZeroMQ if not specified, but if you want 'persistence' you can set the id via `setsockopt` with the `zmq.IDENTITY` flag.

Comment: Thanks, that helped!
Followup questions:
Can the schema by which the `ROUTER` chooses the client id be configured?
How persistent is such a server-generated client id? In which circumstances does it change? Is it possible to control/detect this?

Comment: The only configuration i'm aware of is via `setsockopt`. Any auto generated id will stay the same for the life of a connection. Although i'm not sure if this covers the silent reconnects zeromq does if the underlying network connection goes down. I usually set id's via `setsockopt` as it allows me to connect, send, disconnect then reconnect later and get status updates from previous requests.